# An sssue about CocosBuilder timeline animation

Tags: animation, cocos2d-x, timeline, cocosbuilder

I've created a CCLayer by using Cocosbuilder. There are two timeline animations called "MyAnim1" and "MyAnim2". None of them are auto-run. MyAnim1 is chained to MyAnim2. I'm using CCBAnimationManager to run the first animation. And it works and the second animation is chained to animation 1 as I expected. But here comes a problem. The first animation goback to its initial status when the second animation start. Is this a bug? Is there a way to keep my first animation status to the end status when the second animation starts?

Comment: Did you fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: No, I posted to CocosBuilder forum. But seems nobody cares and I don't have time to do further study recently.